# res.send with forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I want to use a `forEach` loop and if the condition is true I want to send my data by `res.send()`

```
const files = readFilesSync(path.resolve(uploadFolder + `_files`));

files.forEach(el => {
       if (el.name.includes(fName)) {
           res.send(el.name + el.ext);
       } else {
           console.log('Nothing')
       }
});
```

it works fine until I got more than one "file". If the condition is true for 2 files I got an error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: `res.send()` terminates your request-response. You cannot send something after you already sent out a response.

What is it exactly that you want to achieve?

Comment: This error appears because you `send` the response. Once you do that, the server considers the current request as "done". If you want to send a list of files, just "assemble" the list before and send the complete list with a *single* `res.send(fileNames)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `res.send` multiple times while handling the same request. One approach would be to filter the list, concatenate the relevant items and then send them all together. E.g.:

```js
const files = readFilesSync(path.resolve(uploadFolder + `_files`));
const result = 
     files.filter(el => el.name.includes(fName)).map(el => el.name + el.ext).join(',');
if (result.length > 0 ) {
    res.send(result);
} else {
    console.log('Nothing');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `send()` which behind the scene calls `end()`, consider using `write` as demonstrated below:

```
files.forEach(el => {
       if (el.name.includes(fName)) {
           res.write(el.name + el.ext);
       } else {
           console.log('Nothing')
       }
});

res.end()
```